# How do you create a Parent ID and then get the Child to reference it in a threaded commenting system?

Tags: php, comments

I am trying to make a commenting system where comments can be made and people can reply to comments on a deeper level (like reddit). I understand somewhat how the Child references the Parent ID so that it can show up underneath the parent, but how do you actually create the Parent ID, and then get that ID for the child to reference?

Here's an example of what I want:

```
Main Comment
    Reply to Main Comment
    Reply to Main Comment
        Reply to Child Comment
            Reply to Child Child Comment
    Reply to Main Comment
Main Comment
```

And I understand that the depth would be:

```
0
 1
 1
  2
   3
 1
0
```

But how do I assign a Parent ID, so that the First Main Comment is say, AAA, and the second main comment is AAB, and so on?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you storing the comment information? MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent
 - New Comment
   - This comments parent is "New Comment"
   - This comments parent is "New Comment"
 - This Comments parent is "Parent"
```

Parent is "basically" a comment within its self, just more access to formatting.

Answer (score 0):

First, what you want to do is set up the table structure. In the site that I implemented, the tables had the important fields like, `name`, `content`, `email`, etc. Also, it had a `parent_id` field that could reference another comment in the table. This field is `NULL` when the comment is at the top level.

In my PHP script, it would query for all comments that had `parent_id = NULL`, namely, only comments at the top level. Then, while looping through all the top-level comments, I would query for any comments with the `parent_id` equal to the `id` of the comment I was looping through. Then I would style it with an indent.

Your pseudo-code would look like this:

```
// Query for comments
while ($comment = mysqli_fetch_array($comments)) {
  // Render top level comment
  // Query for sub-level comments with parent_id of $comment
  while ($subcomments = mysqli_fetch_array($subcomments)) {
    // Render sub-level comment
  }
}
```